# Write group of equations on separate lines with "where" and "and" in between

Tags: equations

How do I produce the following using LaTeX?

[image]

My solution:

```
\begin{equation}
S  = \left( t^{(0)}, t^{(1)}, \ldots, t^{(n)} \right)
\end{equation}
where:
\begin{equation}
\rho^{(0)} < \rho^{(1)} < \ldots < \rho^{(n)}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
Bs_t_j^{(-1)} < t_e_p^{(j)} < \ldots < Bs_t_j^{(0)} \quad \text{ for }  j = 1, 2, \ldots, n 
\end{equation}
```

My display:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're quite likely using `IEEEtran`.

1. Use `aligned` inside `equation`;
2. don't use `\left` and `\right` when not needed;
3. note `\dots` and not `\ldots`;
4. check the double subscripts.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& S  = ( t^{(0)}, t^{(1)}, \dots, t^{(n)} )
\\
\text{where } & \rho^{(0)} < \rho^{(1)} < \dots < \rho^{(n)}
\\
\text{and } & Bs_{tj}^{(-1)} < t_{ep}^{(j)} < \dots < Bs_{tj}^{(0)}
  \text{ for }  j = 1, 2, \dots, n
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better with NewTX:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& S  = ( t^{(0)}, t^{(1)}, \dots, t^{(n)} )
\\
\text{where } & \rho^{(0)} < \rho^{(1)} < \dots < \rho^{(n)}
\\
\text{and } & Bs_{tj}^{(-1)} < t_{ep}^{(j)} < \dots < Bs_{tj}^{(0)}
  \text{ for }  j = 1, 2, \dots, n 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a way to make where and 'and' left aligned ?

Comment: @HaseebSaeed Yes, of course. I'll add it.